# How to get all of the users that that are listed under user management tab on AWS amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Please bear with me I'm a bit new to AWS amplify and I couldn't find answer to my question online.

All I want is a JavaScript API that returns the users that are listed under user management tab on AWS amplify. Example in screenshot bellow, it should return all 3 emails of the users.

[image]

I searched online and found a thread on gitHub that suggested `listUsers`
https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin/#admin-queries-api
But I don't think it's waht I'm looking for.

In my app for authentication and creating account I use AWS amplify AUTH.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you read this [github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1324) post?

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS Amplify Queries API](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin/#admin-queries-api) has an option for Admin users to `listUsers`